# Using Angular template for Kendo UI Grid detail template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo UI package for Angular JS. I would like to use an Angular template for the row detail, very similar to what is done here:

[Kendo Grid Detail Template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/detailtemplate.html)

Essentially I would like to fetch some data when details are expanded, and pass an angular model to the template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done (so far) with this same need is use the changed event on the Grid to populate a 'SelectedRow' object on the $scope in my controller.  For the DetailTemplate, I have a div that contains a directive that loads the template either from the $templateCache or using $http and compiles it and links it to the $scope.  One of the problems with templates is compiling and linking them to the $scope and the timing of when that takes place.  (My problem was even worse as I needed a different detail template for each row)

```
                $scope.vm.options.productGridOptions = {
                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: $scope.vm.solution.Products,
                    pageSize: 10
                }),
                change: $scope.vm.events.productSelected,
                columns: $scope.vm.columns.productColumns,
                detailTemplate: '<div data-template-detail type="#= EntityTemplateSK #"></div>',
                filterable: false,
                groupable: false,
                pageable: true,
                reorderable: true,
                resizable: true,
                selectable: 'single',
                sortable: true
            };

 myApp.directive('templateDetail', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', 
        function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
            var detailTemplateNumbers = ['21', '22', '23', '26', '45', '69'];
            var getTemplate = function (templateNumber) {
                var baseUrl = '/App/Product/Views/',
                    templateName = 'productdetail.html',
                    templateUrl = baseUrl + templateName;

                if (detailTemplateNumbers.filter(function (element) { return element === templateNumber; })[0]) {
                    templateName = 'productTemplate' + templateNumber + '.html';
                    templateUrl = baseUrl + templateName;
                }

                return $http.get(templateUrl, { cache: $templateCache });
            };

            var linker = function ($scope, element, attrs) {

                var loader = getTemplate(attrs.type.toString());

                if (loader) {
                    loader.success(function (html) {
                        element.html(html);
                    }).then(function () {
                        element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())($scope.$parent));
                    });
                }
            };

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    type: '='
                },
                link: linker
            };
    }]);
```

Comment: Cant get this working. The detail directive does not work at all, don't stop at any breakpoint. How does your change function look like? And how do you get the data in your template file?

Comment: The directive to load a dynamic template uses shared scope do it gets its data from the parent scope of the grid.  There's other ways to handle this like passing in what it needs and I use that pattern on other directives I have but this one needed to load the detail view data from the parent scope.  I've since removed the change event from this in my code.  The data is all loaded on the array that the grid is bound to so the detail views bind to 'dataItem.detailObject.fieldName'.